# Alexa Skill Handler State (Alexa.CreateStateHandler) explanation

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I'm having a hard time finding information on the web about this.

Can someone explain to me the purpose of passing a state variable to

```
Alexa.CreateStateHandler(states.STATEVARIABLE, {})
```

What does that do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may pass state variable if there're multiple states in your skill. Let me explain it with example.
There's audio skill and it can be in 3 states.

1. Start
2. Play
3. Resume

If we look from intent's perspective, there can be multiple intents i.e. Launch, Help etc. And you want different behaviors in different states. For example **Help** in:

1. **Start State**: Say 'start audio' to play the podcast
2. **Play state:** You're listening to audio#1. You can play next, previous or stop
3. **Resume state:** You were listening to audio#1. Would you like to resume. Say yes to resume and no to stop.

So what we do is to create multiple states via createStateHandler, and add "Help" intent in all of them. On backend DB, we maintain record of user session and state where he/she left (please note, default state in this case will be start state).

Alexa SDK (alexa-sdk) manages it and fire the intent of that particular state.

States help in different cases i.e. games, audio playback etc. but if multiple states are not the requirement of your skill, you can ignore it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense.